How can I deliver a message by WebSocket?
I'm struggling to have a message delivered from a user to another one connected in the same net by Websocket. The connection between both of them is well suceeded but as I try to send the message it doesn't reaches the destination. It's is probably something related to the non-existence of chat threads or the use of callback functions that I don't dominate.
Chat_Thread.py (only important parts):
async def talk(self):
        self.interface = Interface(self.cliente.nome, send_callback=self.send_message)
        self.interface.print("Você está conversando com " + self.cliente.nome)
        async for message in self.socket:
          print(f"Recebendo mensagem: {message}")
          self.interface.print(f"[{self.cliente.nome}]: {message}")

async def send_message(self, message):
        if self.socket:          
            print(f"Enviando mensagem: {message}")
            await self.socket.send(message)
            self.interface.print(f"Você: {message}")
        else:
          print(f"DEU MERDA")

conexao_socket.py (only important parts):
async def websocket_handler(websocket: websockets.server.WebSocketServerProtocol, path: str) -> None: 
  client_name: str = websocket.request_headers.get("client-name")
  nome_valido = validar_nome_cliente(client_name)
  try:
    if not nome_valido: await send_error(websocket, "Nome inválido")
    message = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"(websocket_handler) Mensagem recebida: {message}")
    if message != MensagemSocket.SOLICITAR_CONEXAO.value: await websocket.send(json.dumps({"error": "Mensagem inválida"}))
    thread_aberta = shared.chat_threads.get(client_name)
    if thread_aberta is not None: await send_error(websocket, "Conexão já solicitada ou ativa")
    print(f"Conexão solicitada por {client_name}")
  except websockets.exceptions.InvalidMessage: return
  shared.chat_threads[client_name] = Chat_Thread(
    Cliente(client_name, websocket.remote_address), 
    StatusChat.SOLICITACAO_PENDENTE,
    socket = websocket, 
  )
  print(f"Chat_Thread criado para {client_name}")
  await websocket.wait_closed()

interface.py(only important parts):
def send_message(self):
        message = self.entry.get()
        print(f"(interface.send_messge) mensagem: {message}")
        if message and self.send_callback:
            # Use run_coroutine_threadsafe to ensure the coroutine runs in the event loop
            print(f"Vai executar asyncio.ensure_future")
            asyncio.ensure_future(self.send_callback(message), loop=self.loop)
            self.print(f"executou asyncio.ensure_future Você: {message}")  # Display the message locally
            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)

main.py
import asyncio
import shared
from validacao import validar_nome_cliente
from websockets.server import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServer, serve
import socket as EnumSocketFamily
from server_handler import me_registrar
from graceful_exit import GracefulExit
from menu import exibir_menu
from sys import argv
from random import choices, choice
from string import ascii_lowercase, digits
from conexao_socket import websocket_handler, inicializar_socket_headers
from cliente import Cliente

get_client_host = lambda: 'localhost'
def criar_nome_cliente():
    if len(argv) <= 1 or not validar_nome_cliente(argv[1]):
        identifier = ''.join(choices(ascii_lowercase, k=4))
        print(f"Nome não inserido ou inválido, seu nome será {identifier}")
        return identifier
    else:
        return argv[1]

def criar_url(server: WebSocketServer):
    sock = server.sockets[0]
    if sock.family == EnumSocketFamily.AF_INET:
        return "%s:%d" % sock.getsockname()
    elif sock.family == EnumSocketFamily.AF_INET6:
        return "[%s]:%d" % sock.getsockname()[:2]
    elif sock.family == EnumSocketFamily.AF_UNIX:
        return sock.getsockname()
    else:
        return str(sock.getsockname())

def criar_cliente(server: WebSocketServer):
    shared.me = Cliente(criar_nome_cliente(), criar_url(server))
    print(f"Seja bem vindo, {shared.me.nome}!")

async def start_ws_server():
    server = await serve(websocket_handler, get_client_host(), 0)
    criar_cliente(server)
    me_registrar()
    inicializar_socket_headers()
    
    print(f"WebSocket server running at {shared.me.endereco}")
    menu_task = asyncio.create_task(exibir_menu())
    
    try:
        await asyncio.Future()
    except GracefulExit:
        print("Received exit signal, shutting down...")
    finally:
        menu_task.cancel()
        server.close()
        await server.wait_closed()
        print("WebSocket server stopped")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(start_ws_server())
    

As I hit send button nothing reaches the destination, the message only appears for the sender.
send_message from Chat_Thread.py is never used, this might be a problem.
Don't worry about connecting the users this is working fine and the chat interfaces are loading for both
